# How to display filtered content after clicking on static block link on the basis of attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I have create static block with some hyperlinks name as "lenovo" "samsang" "HP" and also having attribute drop-down name as "camera_megapixel" with values "2mp" , "5mp" "8mp" . after clicking on "lenovo" link of static block there will be only open those mobile which having "2mp" and after clicking on "samsang" link of static block there will be only open those mobile which having "5mp" and so on. Thanks in advance.

Following is my static block content,

```
<div class="collections-wrap">
<div class="block-title"><span>Mobile</span></div>
<ul class="collections">
<li class="collect collect3"><a href="#"><span>lenovo</span></a></li>
<li class="collect collect4"><a href="#"><span>samsang</span></a></li>
<li class="collect collect5"><a href="#"><span>HP</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have followed this link https://www.atwix.com/magento/products-list-cms/
but not getting.please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anybody knows answer please share

Comment: your code makes no sense/list.phtml does not match anything as per what you are expecting. - for example, how does this link `<a href="#"><span>lenovo</span></a>` translate to load that list.phtml file? Do you have some javascript click event defined on those classes that intercepts the link at loads the page? What you show, simple has no correlation to teh article you showed. Sure you pasted the correct list.phtml file? Simply makes no sense.